# Python recognized in PyCharm, but not in Windows command line

Tags: python, windows

I recently uninstalled python 32 bit and installed the 64 bit version. Now, python is not recognized in the command line. When I type in:

```
python
```

I receive this error:

```
No Python at 'C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe'
```

However, the python 64 bit version is running fine in PyCharm.

I have tried adding python to the path in the advanced system settings, but python is still not recognized. When I installed python 64 bit, I checked the box that should add python to the path.

My python 64 bit is located at:

```
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.8
```

Comment: have you tried `python3`, `python3.8`? did you check to see if it was truly added to the system path?

Comment: It is added to the system path. I am trying to launch jupyter notebook with pip install notebook, and I get the same error. When I type in python3, however, it is recognized.

Comment: *"python is not recognized in the command line"* - That's incorrect. It *is* recognized, as indicated by the error diagnostic. If it weren't recognized, the system wouldn't report a specific location where it was expecting Python. More diligence is required in solving issues.

Comment: @IInspectable yeah, I feel like there's an issue with the path - but it's also likely that an alias already points to it correctly

Comment: I uninstalled python 32 bit. I am not sure why the the "python" command is still searching in the incorrect location. Sorry, I'm new to Python, thanks for the responses.

Comment: Run `where.exe python` to find `python` commands in `PATH`.